# supported place type for 'Historical place'

Tags: android, google-places-api

What is the supported place type for Historical place in google-places-api .I tried to use historical_place but it didn't retrieve the places

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

this list all the places types supported by google Places API. 
unfortunately `Historical Place` is not included